# Enable disable HTML table element with JQuery in disabled <TR>

Tags: jquery, html, disabled-control, isenabled

I am creating a dynamic HTML table with JQuery. Sample code is below.

```
var tbody=$("#myTable tbody");

var tableRow;

if(somevariableIsTrue)
   tableRow=$("<tr>").attr("disabled",true);
else
   tableRow=$("<tr>");

var td=$("<td>");
    td.appendTo(tableRow);

var tdn=#("<td>");
tdn.appendTo(tableRow);

 tableRow.appendTo(tbody);
```

now I create different TDs and append to the tableRow. If the disabled attribute of the row is TRUE obviously all the TDs for that row will be disabled too. But I want that my first TD of disabled row shouldn NOT be disabled as its a checkbox column on its click I want to enable/disable the same row. I tried different ways to get the checkbox in the first column and tried to enable it but all fails. Can some one suggest me how to do this in JQuery

**EDIT**
Hope this screen shot helps to understand my requirement
[image]

as seen in the image first row is disabled including the first td with checkbox. I want to checkbox column to be enabled all the time so that on checking it the row becomes enabled and un checking leaves the row disabled again.

Comment: The `tr` element doesn't have a `disabled` attribute. If you want to disable the inputs within that `tr`, you need to add the attribute to all of them individually.

Comment: Well it works with tr and disables all the other elements in that tr as required. I do not want to iterate each td to enable disable the elements so I chose this method.

Comment: You should also consider a lightweight templating engine.

Comment: @V.B is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1hvbsvh3/) what you want?

Comment: @Regent actually my table Row is created even before I add tds to it and while creating the Row its decided whether its going to be enabled or disabled. So when tds are added to DISABLED row they become disabled too. But I want that first column MUST NOT be disabled even of the row is disabled.

Comment: @V.B you can remove `disable` from `tr`, can't you? And before removing  `disable` from `tr` you can disable all required `td`.

Comment: Please see the above comment I want to avoid enable/disable for individual tds

Comment: @V.B and I tell you once more: you can disable all `td` **except first one** instead of disabling whole `tr`. Doesn't it make what you want?

Comment: My bad Regent. I misread your fiddle. yes it solves my problem.thanks alot

Comment: @V.B you claim disabled works on <tr>. Beware this does not work on modern browsers. I suppose you're using an old version of IE. Instead you should disable the form elements that are children of that table row.

Comment: Well I see it working in IE 11.

Comment: The `tr` being the "parent" of all your `td` on that row, you can't really tell JQ to disable just some `td`s without explicitly specifying others `td`s not to be disabled. So, the easiest way would be to use `.find` to get all `td`s in that row, as mentioned by @Regent

Answer (score 1):

You could just call

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

or

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
```

on all your checkboxes.  This would essentially re-enable all of your checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
// first row checkboxes
$('tr td:first-child input[type="checkbox"]').click( function() {
   //enable/disable all except checkboxes, based on the row is checked or not
   $(this).closest('tr').find(":input:not(:first)").attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

See it working in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/1rhrco48/)